# How to replace whitespace with one blank using sed?

Tags: sed, whitespace

Using
sed "s/[[:blank:]]*/ /g" a>b
doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the asterisk to a plus sign:

```
sed "s/[[:blank:]]\+/ /g" a>b
```

or use an alternative that means the same thing:

```
sed "s/[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]*/ /g" a>b
```

or

```
sed "s/[[:blank:]]\{1,\}/ /g" a>b
```

Also, it's more helpful to post error messages or precise ways that behavior differs from expectations since "doesn't seem to work" conveys very little information.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit distracted and couldn't make sense of the fact that suddenly there were spaces where there were none before. :)

Comment: @user: Since `*` matches *zero* or more occurrences of a pattern, it can match the beginning and end of a string. Here's a simple example that turns three characters into five: `echo ' a '|sed 's/a*/x/g'`.

Comment: The first time I tried it, if I remember correctly,sed "s/[[:blank:]]\+/ /g" a>b

Comment: [pessed enter for \n]
worked fine, but now that I'm trying it again, it, the only line of the three versions you provided, doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @user: I'm afraid I don't understand. What do you mean by "the only line of the three versions you provided"? What does an example of your input look like? Do any of my versions work?

Comment: a     bv   input     aaa endinput

Comment: (Apparently this site compresses whitespace in comments). I just tried this on some files containing multiple tabs and spaces.

Comment: @user: What version of `sed`?

Comment: @user: I have gnuwin32 `sed` version 4.2 and all three `sed` commands work for me.

Comment: I realized that I've been typing + instead of \+. Thanks for helping me.